# Using Django authentication system with existing hashed passwords

Tags: python, django, perl

I have a very old Perl CGI system with a table of users. The passwords are stored as computed hashes using the  `crypt` function. I am looking to migrate the system to Django, and I would like to keep the user data while using the Django table structure.

One option would be to copy all the user/password data an `auth_user` table and use a custom authentication function since I have existing password hashes.

Do I have a better option?

If I go with this option then how can it be implemented?

Comment: Your approach sounds reasonable. If you cannot get them out again, do that. You can also add a marker to remember which passwords are old, then upgrade the passwords one by one when users log in and use a more modern hashing algorithm.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard the very old code is not relevant to the question. They are not asking how to translate it. This question is about the process, which is a little bit off-topic I believe. Maybe it's better suited for [softwareengineering.se], though I am usually wrong when suggesting that because I don't frequent that site. The second part _how can this be implemented_ is definitely off-topic because we're not a code-writing service.

Comment: @simbabque I did think of upgrading the passwords once I got them to work the first time around. The 'how' part is Django specific.  Like is there a method I need to override? I have a reference here that I can look at.  Thanks

Comment: @user2125853: *"Do I have a better option?"* What would you consider to be "better". What is wrong with the solution that you have proposed? As **simbabque** says, this is rather off topic as you don't have a programming problem except in a very broad sense. Without a copy of the original passwords, you can't silently "upgrade" them.

Comment: @Borodin I was not asking for an option in broad sense.  I am not too familiar with Django.  What I was looking for if Django had an option (e.g using the existing user table instead of auth_user).  I do appreciate the insight provided here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for writing up a custom authentication backend are in
[*Customizing authentication in Django*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/)

Since Borodin asked and since you might find it handy to have a sample more specific to your request, I went ahead and wrote up an example  that authenticates against a `crypt`-based file (e.g., `htpasswd`).

If the backend finds a user with a matching password in the `crypt` file, it looks for a standard Django user and returns it.  If it can't find one it creates one.  Obviously you would need to decide how you want to handle the actual details of your implementation.

#### ./authbackend/__init__.py

```
import crypt
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CryptBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        crypt_file = getattr(settings, "CRYPT_DB", None)
        if crypt_file is None:
            return None

        password_match = False
        with open(crypt_file,"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                (user, crypted_pass) = line.rstrip().split(":")
                if user == username:
                    password_match = crypt.crypt(password, crypted_pass) == crypted_pass
                    break

        if not password_match:
            return None

        # found a match in our crypt database
        try:
            django_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            django_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email='', password=password)
            django_user.is_staff = True
            django_user.save()

        return django_user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

That new custom backend is loaded based on additions to `settings.py`.  In my example, I'm keeping the default Django backend and simply adding my new custom one. Django checks them in order, so it will try a standard Django authentication and if that doesn't work moves on to my custom one. The `CRYPT_DB` parameter is the path to the `htpasswd` file.

#### settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'authbackend.CryptBackend',
]

CRYPT_DB = '/path/to/your/passwd.file'
```

And for completeness, an example of the format (`htpasswd`) that the above is  checking against.

#### passwd.file

```
jill:C.1oP2DOot4MY
jack:qJn7lPS/VNssM
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you